# When Print Preview styles not working for Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem with cross browser compatibility, the Print Preview showing blank for Chrome and Edge.

The logs shows this:

> [Deprecation] Styling master document from stylesheets defined in HTML
>   Imports is deprecated. Please refer to some url for
>   possible migration paths.

The code for showing the Print Preview looks as following:

```
alternativePrint(resultId: string){ // Assuming that resultId is unique.
    var printWindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=800,width=1240');

    printWindow.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');

    printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/css/styles.css">');

    printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById(resultId).innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    printWindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    printWindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();

    return true;
  }

  call(tel:string){
    window.open('tel:'+tel);
  }
```

This code works all fine on Firefox but for some reason it is not working for Chrome nor Microsoft Edge.

I already tried this link but for some reason I can still not be able to fix it:

https://github.com/TakayoshiKochi/deprecate-style-in-html-imports